# Removing the 'Computers' menu item from the ATV 2 menu

Tags: appletv

How can you remove the 'Computers' menu item from the Apple TV menu? I do not plan to use Home Sharing, and would like to remove this menu item altogether from the main screen. ATV can be jailbroken or not.

What steps can be taken to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be jailbroken to do this.  SSH into the ATV2 and then:

1. cd /Applications/AppleTV.app/
2. mkdir Appliances_Disabled
3. mv Appliances/Computers.frappliance Appliances_Disabled

Reboot.

You can move the Computers.frappliance directory back into /Applications/AppleTV.app/Appliances if you ever want to see it again.